# Elasticsearch/Logstash duplicating output when use schedule

Tags: logstash

Im using Elasticsearch with Logstash. 
I want to update indexes when database changes. So i decided to use LS **schedule**. But every 1 minute output appended by database table records. 
Example: contract table has 2 rows.
First 1 minute total: 2, 1 minute after total output is : 4;
How can i solve this?

There is my config file. Command is *bin/logstash -f contract.conf*

```
input {
        jdbc {
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/resource"
            jdbc_user => "postgres"
            jdbc_validate_connection => true
            jdbc_driver_library => "/var/www/html/iltodgeree/logstash/postgres.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
            statement => "SELECT * FROM contracts;"
            schedule => "* * * * *"
            codec => "json"
        }
    }

    output {
        elasticsearch {
            index => "resource_contracts"
            document_type => "metadata"
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your output by specifying the `document_id` setting and use the ID field from your contracts table. That way, you'll never get duplicates.

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "resource_contracts"
        document_type => "metadata"
        document_id => "%{ID_FIELD}"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

Also if you have an update timestamp in your `contracts` table, you can modify the SQL statement in your input like below in order to only copy the records that changed recently:

```
        statement => "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE timestamp > :sql_last_value;"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, But another issue is delete action. 
When i deleted record from database, what configuration i should use ?

Comment: Okey. I will try it. Thank you! :-)